# Image zoom on multiple images

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop, magnify

I've used a pretty standard image zoom effect from the following example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_magnifier_glass.asp

The HTML + CSS + JS is pretty much exactly what is used in the example above.

This works perfectly on 1 image. However when multiple images are used it only works on the first image.

I'm pretty sure it's to do with using getElementById instead of querySelectorAll for some things (possibly var img and var result) hence why it's only applying to the first instance of #myimage.

Can anyone help me run this code but loop it over ALL images (with #myimage as the ID)?

Much appreciated!

Original code below:

```
JAVASCRIPT:
// enable image zoom

function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  
  
  /* Create lens: */
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  
  
  /* Insert lens: */
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  
  
  
  
  /* Calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens: */
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /* Set background properties for the result DIV */
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /* Execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens: */
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /* And also for touch screens: */
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /* Prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image */
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Get the cursor's x and y positions: */
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /* Calculate the position of the lens: */
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /* Prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image: */
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    /* Set the position of the lens: */
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /* Display what the lens "sees": */
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /* Get the x and y positions of the image: */
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /* Calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image: */
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /* Consider any page scrolling: */
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}


imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
```

```
HTML:
<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/250' id="myimage">

<div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result"></div>
```

Comment: You're going to have to post your code so we can get an idea of what you're doing and what might be going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Cully . Code posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function magnify(img, zoom) {
   var glass, w, h, bw;
  /* Create magnifier glass: */
  glass = document.createElement("DIV");
  glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");

  /* Insert magnifier glass: */
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);

  /* Set background properties for the magnifier glass: */
  glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
  bw = 3;
  w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
  h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;

  /* Execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image: */
  glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);

  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  function moveMagnifier(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /* Prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image */
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Get the cursor's x and y positions: */
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    x = pos.x;
    y = pos.y;
    /* Prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image: */
    if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {x = img.width - (w / zoom);}
    if (x < w / zoom) {x = w / zoom;}
    if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {y = img.height - (h / zoom);}
    if (y < h / zoom) {y = h / zoom;}
    /* Set the position of the magnifier glass: */
    glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
    glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
    /* Display what the magnifier glass "sees": */
    glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
  }

  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /* Get the x and y positions of the image: */
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /* Calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image: */
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /* Consider any page scrolling: */
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}
[…document.querySelectorAll(“#myimage”)].forEach( img => {
 magnify(img,3);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this Nour! It just about does the job in a slightly different way which is fine with me :)

One thing that is happening is that when initially loaded in incognito it doesn't seem to work 100% of the time, but when refreshed it works perfectly. Any idea how to force this to work or why that's happening? The page in question is here: https://matthewv12.sg-host.com/product/classic-fleecy/

Comment: It can be a loading issue, try instead

    document.querySelectorAll('#myimage').forEach( img => {
 img.onload = () => { magnify(img,3)};
 
})

Comment: And how exactly it's working slightly different? Do you mean the style of the magnifier glass?

Comment: Thanks so much Nour, I'll try that. I just meant it was a different style in that this follows the cursor while the original was fixed, but I actually prefer this. One other thing if you check out that link - the first image works great, but then the alignment of the zoom box changes when another image is selected. The corner attaches to the cursor, rather than the center of the zoom box. Any idea why that is?